# How to force the browser to maximize (like pressing F11) from an NPAPI plugin?

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin

I have a scriptable NPAPI browser plugin.
I would like to expose a method to javascript "MaximizeBrowser",
that will cause the browser window to maximize (as if the user pressed <kbd>F11</kbd> in the broswer).
Is there a way to achieve that?

The selected answer works (at least on Windows)!
 Here is my code, in case someone needs:

```
// simulate F11 keyboard key press
keybd_event(VK_F11,MapVirtualKey(VK_F11,0),0,0); 
keybd_event(VK_F11,MapVirtualKey(VK_F11,0),KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's certainly no supported way using the NPAPI APIs, but depending on what OS you are targeting you could try using OS-level calls to simulate a keyboard event matching the browser's full-screen mode. That will of course be fragile since it depends on every browser you are targeting a) having a full screen mode, and b) never changing the shortcut.

If your goal is to have your plugin content be full-screen, perhaps you should instead consider opening a full-screen window from your plugin, which is how other NPAPI plugins go full-screen.

Comment: yeah... this is pretty much your only option

Comment: Good idea, I will simulate F11 key press. Good enough for now.

Comment: I do it as a demo-hack, instead of opening "real" full screen from my windowless plugin. I have to do it in order to display semi-transparent content (e.g. flash) from the browser beneath, on top of the plugin's content. A bit complicated... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to maximize the browser window to full screen with JavaScript. While this is unfortunate for your genuine requirement, it is considered a security restriction.

Comment: But the NPAPI plugin is not bound by that sandbox.